# How can I filter out the similar attribute names in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, sorting, filter

I'm doing a project where I'm pulling data from an API, and it's all going well so far but I can't seem to figure out how to filter out the ingredients and measurements specifically.

The array looks like this:

```js
{
  "idMeal": "52977",
  "strMeal": "Corba",
  "strDrinkAlternate": null,
  "strCategory": "Side",
  "strArea": "Turkish",
  "strInstructions": "",
  "strMealThumb": "https://www.themealdb.com/images/media/meals/58oia61564916529.jpg",
  "strTags": "Soup",
  "strYoutube": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVnZd8A84z4",
  "strIngredient1": "Lentils",
  "strIngredient2": "Onion",
  "strIngredient3": "Carrots",
  "strIngredient4": "Tomato Puree",
  "strIngredient5": "Cumin",
  "strIngredient6": "Paprika",
  "strIngredient7": "Mint",
  "strIngredient8": "Thyme",
  "strIngredient9": "Black Pepper",
  "strIngredient10": "Red Pepper Flakes",
  "strIngredient11": "Vegetable Stock",
  "strIngredient12": "Water",
  "strIngredient13": "Sea Salt",
  "strIngredient14": "",
  "strIngredient15": "",
  "strIngredient16": "",
  "strIngredient17": "",
  "strIngredient18": "",
  "strIngredient19": "",
  "strIngredient20": "",
  "strMeasure1": "1 cup ",
  "strMeasure2": "1 large",
  "strMeasure3": "1 large",
  "strMeasure4": "1 tbs",
  "strMeasure5": "2 tsp",
  "strMeasure6": "1 tsp ",
  "strMeasure7": "1/2 tsp",
  "strMeasure8": "1/2 tsp",
  "strMeasure9": "1/4 tsp",
  "strMeasure10": "1/4 tsp",
  "strMeasure11": "4 cups ",
  "strMeasure12": "1 cup ",
  "strMeasure13": "Pinch",
  "strMeasure14": " ",
  "strMeasure15": " ",
  "strMeasure16": " ",
  "strMeasure17": " ",
  "strMeasure18": " ",
  "strMeasure19": " ",
  "strMeasure20": " ",
  "strSource": "https://findingtimeforcooking.com/main-dishes/red-lentil-soup-corba/",
  "strImageSource": null,
  "strCreativeCommonsConfirmed": null,
  "dateModified": null
}
```

I'd like to specifically take out all of the attribute names containing "strIngredient" and put those all into a separate array, and same with "strMeasure".

```js
const query = async function () {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s="
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);

    data.meals.forEach((recipe) => {
      const recipeName = recipe.strMeal;
      const recipeImage = recipe.strMealThumb;
      const recipeRegion = recipe.strArea;
      const recipeCategory = recipe.strCategory;
      const recipeInstructions = recipe.strInstructions;
      const recipeLink = recipe.strSource;
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You already have a loop, just check if the key  contains "strIngredient" through regular expressions. If it does put it in an array. You pretty much already described yourself how to do it.

Comment: Yes I know the general idea of how to do it, I just don't know how to apply it. I don't know which array methods to use.

Answer (score 2):

See the code below. You'll the all the `strIngredients` in the `ingredients` array and all the `strMeasure` ins the `measures` array.

```js
const query = async function () {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(
            "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s="
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);

        data.meals.forEach((recipe) => {
            const recipeName = recipe.strMeal;
            const recipeImage = recipe.strMealThumb;
            const recipeRegion = recipe.strArea;
            const recipeCategory = recipe.strCategory;
            const recipeInstructions = recipe.strInstructions;
            const recipeLink = recipe.strSource;
            const ingredients = Object.keys(recipe).filter(k => k.includes('strIngredient')).map(k => recipe[k]);
            const measures = Object.keys(recipe).filter(k => k.includes('strMeasure')).map(k => recipe[k]);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: Is it wise to create the variables inside the forEach? Will they not only be accessible inside that scope?

Answer (score 0):

```
const strIngredient = Object.keys(data.meals)
  .filter(x => x.includes('strIngredient'))
  .reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = data.meals[key]
  }, [])

const strMeasure = Object.keys(data.meals)
  .filter(x => x.includes('strMeasure'))
  .reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = data.meals[key]
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

This builds the recipe using all the data from their feed, but moving the ingredients and measurements into their own arrays

```js
let recipes = []

const query = async function() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s="
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    // console.log(data);
    //"strIngredient" and put those all into a separate array, and same with "strMeasure".
    data.meals.forEach((recipe) => {
      let newRecipe = {
        ingredients: [],
        measurements: []
      }
      //console.log(recipe)
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(recipe)) {

        let pair = {};
        pair[key] = value;
        if (key.indexOf('strIngredient') !== -1) newRecipe.ingredients.push(pair);
        else if (key.indexOf('strMeasure') !== -1) newRecipe.measurements.push(pair);
        else newRecipe[key] = value;
      }
      recipes.push(newRecipe)
    });

    console.log(recipes)

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

query()
```